# Understanding Counter - EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

When an coil rotor is moving around a magnetic field there is -V induced to resist the input V.

Let's take an example, a 12 V DC motor induces -10V, and the actual running voltage is 2V.

If there we're no -V in the process, the motor would preform a lot better?
What is the advantages and disadvantages of counter EMF? Is it wasting energy?

I understand the concept, but I can not fathom how initially, the motor runs at 12V then drops to 2V(actual) and still preforms the same? 
Are all current motors today lose 70%+ of their input voltage due to counter EMF?

Answer (score 1):

The back emf voltage actually gives the motor its mechanical power and it allows to control the motor speed.

Let us take a look at the formulas.

The terminal voltage of the motor is
$$
v = Ri + k_V \omega
$$
with the electrical resistance $R$ of the winding, the voltage constant $k_V$ of the motor and the shaft speed $\omega$.

The torque delivered by the motor is
$$
T = k_T i.
$$
with the torque constant $k_T\approx k_V$. The torque can be reduced by damping and friction causing $k_T\stackrel{<}{\approx} k_V$. Nevertheless, here we neglect mechanical losses and set $k:=k_T=k_V$.

With this simplification the mechanical shaft power is
$$
P_{\rm mech} = T\omega = k \omega i
$$

The electrical power is
$$
P_{\rm el} = vi = Ri^2 + k\omega i = Ri^2 + P_{\rm mech}
$$

As you see the back emf voltage contributes to the mechanical work and the difference $Ri$ of the terminal voltage and the emf voltage contributes to the power that is converted into heat.

Furthermore, if $\omega$ comes close to $\frac{v}{k_V}$ the current and therefore the torque decreases. If the motor torque and the load torque are balanced then the motor speed keeps constant. This way you can control the motor speed via the terminal voltage. If there was no load and no damping the required torque would be zero and therefore the required current would be zero. In this case you would just have the proportionality $v=k_V\omega$ and you could directly adjust the speed via the voltage.

Regarding your question in the comments below:

The mechanical work delivered by the motor within the time interval from $t_0$ to $t_1$ is
$$
W_{\rm mech}(t_0,t_1) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} P_{\rm mech}(t) d t
= \int_{t_0}^{t_1} T(t)\omega(t) d t
$$

Comment: is $P_{\rm mech}$ = $T\omega$ ,the same as work done = $Torque$$\theta$ then over $t$ to find the power? $Torque$ = $F$$r$?

Comment: I have included the work integral into the answer.